# Laravel facade with bind only instantiates once

Tags: php, laravel, facade, service-provider

I'm making a Laravel package and I'm using a service provider and a facade to make my class available.

I want that every time the user calls my class like `ImageUpload::myfunc()` a new instance of the class `ImageUploadManager` is created.

When I use `app('imageupload')->myfunc()` it works the way I want it but i'd like something easier and "prettier" than that.

Is it possible? I'm not new to laravel but I'm somewhat new to ServiceProviders and Facades. From my understanding the only thing I needed to do was call the function `bind` instead of `singleton`.

I also understand that the facades are just glorified arrays. So it makes sense that the key `imageupload` is already instantiated so Laravel doesn't do it again, but other packages do it I just don't understand how.

My Facade:

```php
class ImageUpload extends Facade
{
    protected static function getFacadeAccessor()
    {
        return 'imageupload';
    }
}
```

My Service Provider:

```php
public function register(): void
{
    $this->app->bind('imageupload', function ($app) {
       return new ImageUploadManager();
    });
}
```

In a controller somewhere

```php
ImageUpload::myfunc(); //It's always the same instance

app('imageupload')->myfunc(); //It's a new instance everytime. This is what I want
```

Comment: What happens if you use `app()` helper in provider's `register` method [instead `$this->app`]?

Comment: @Tpojka same thing.
`app()->bind('imageupload', function ($app) {
            return new ImageUploadManager();
        });
`

Comment: Facades are not glorified arrays, they are static proxies and they cache the instance by default; has nothing to do with the binding ... it almost sounds like you want a factory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching how other packages do it, I found one that was similar to mine and figured out how they did it.

Every time my class is called statically I create a new instance of it. I found this solution by looking at this [package](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf).

I changed my facade to this:

```php
class ImageUpload extends Facade
{
    protected static function getFacadeAccessor()
    {
        return 'imageupload';
    }


    public static function __callStatic($method, $args)
    {
        /** @var \Illuminate\Contracts\Foundation\Application|null */
        $app = static::getFacadeApplication();
        if (!$app) {
            throw new RuntimeException('Facade application has not been set.');
        }

        // Resolve a new instance, avoid using a cached instance
        $instance = $app->make(static::getFacadeAccessor());

        return $instance->$method(...$args);
    }
}
```

I don't know if this is the correct way to do it, it was the way that I found.